# Play framework 2 Java, return chunked response

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, chunks

Based on the following code example that returns chunked data from Play server,
the `out.write` shouldn't create response each time it is called?
when using post client I get only 1 response which contains that wholl data with all the data.

I need to return a huge file from the server in chunks which should be downloaded in the client.
Any ideas?

```
public static Result index(){ 
// Prepare a chunked text stream 
Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() 
{ 
    // Called when the stream is ready 
    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) 
    { 
        out.write("kiki");
        out.write("foo");
        out.write("bar");
        out.close();
     }
 };// Serves this stream with 200 OK 
return ok(chunks); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of chunks depends on the chunk size, which usually defaults to 1024 KB throughout the framework. Your output is too small and thus only one chunk is sent.